# How do you move a drawing in javascript up down right and left

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I was wondering how to move the red ball right and left (I already did, but its not working) and also how to move it up and down.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var ball;
var obstacle;
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var redballRadius = 10;
var ballRadius = 20;
var rightpressed = false;
var leftpressed = false;
var ballX = (canvas.width - redballDiameter) / 2;
var redballDiameter = redballRadius * 2;

function startGame() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ball = new drawBall(30, 30, 'red', 20, 10);
    obstacle = new drawObstacle(40, 30, 'blue', 15, 10);
    if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    if(rightpressed && ballX < canvas.width-redballDiameter) {
        ballX += 7;
    }
    else if(leftpressed && ballX > 0) {
        ballX -= 7;
    }
}

//keyboard controls
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightpressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftpressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightpressed = false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftpressed = false;
    }
}

function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(30, 30, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();


}

function drawObstacle() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 10, 1 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

setInterval(startGame, 10);
```

I am basically wondering how to move it up down right and left with the keys. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code. In your life cycle, you are calling `drawBall`, now sure what you are trying to do with the `new` there. anyways, I updated the function to use the `ballX` your key handling logic updates.

```
function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ballX, 30, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

here is the working code pen. http://codepen.io/poda/pen/aNPPEp

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to make it move up and down too? Im not sure how. @SitianLui

Comment: @splav yeah. I will add it to the code pen when I get a little time. I will let you know here!

Answer (score 0):

move a ball to up, down, right and left.

it would be better to use `object` than use global variable of x_pos and y_pos of ball

```
function drawBall() {
  this.ball_x = 30;
  this.ball_y = 30;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.ball_x, this.ball_y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  },
  this.move = function() {
    if(rightpressed && this.ball_x < canvas.width-redballDiameter) {
        this.ball_x += 5;
    }
    else if(leftpressed && this.ball_x > redballDiameter) {
        this.ball_x -= 5;
    }
    else if(uppressed && this.ball_y > redballDiameter) {
        this.ball_y -= 5;
    }
    else if(downpressed && this.ball_y < canvas.height - redballDiameter) {
        this.ball_y += 5;
    }
  },
  this.collision = function() {
    //stuff
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/t0vxqe1m/)